# Can I add changed files to an already merged gerrit?

Tags: git, gerrit

I checkout a branch, say X from master branch, added my code and later pushed to gerrit. It got merged to the master branch.

My teammate was working on another change and when they submit their change, they found that my X branch code there was a test failure.
They cannot push the code to gerrit unless my tests are fixed which I checked in X branch.

How should I go ahead?
Can I still edit the X branch - amend commit - push to merged gerrit?
Or should I go ahead by creating a new branch and edit my test file there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IF it is already merged/published, then [adding/modifying files to a change](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/user-inline-edit.html#add-files) would not apply.

It is easier to treat that as a new change to be pushed, reviewed and merged.

Comment: Thanks!! If I update my branch X and commit without using amend, will that be taken as a new commit with a new gerrit url?

Comment: @user2855892 if that was alreay merged, it is better to isolate the fix in its own branch, based on the latest (fetch) master state.

Comment: yes it was already merged. Thanks, I will go with the new branch.